# Conditions on differentiation of integral

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, under what additional condition on $f$, would the following hold: for $0<l<h$,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{l}\int_h^{h+l}f(s)ds \xrightarrow{h\to0}f(0)
\end{align}
I know that if $f$ is real analytic, it's easy to see the convergence hold. Is there a more general assumption than being analytic?

Comment: $l<h<0$, and $h\to0$ implies $l\to0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, by fundamental theorem of calculus for all $h$ and $l<h$ there is some $\xi_{h,l}\in (h,h+l)$ such that $\frac1{l}\int_h^{h+l}f(x)\,dx=f(\xi_{h,l})$. As $h\to 0^+$, we have $0<\xi_{h,l}<h+l<2h$, therefore $f(\xi_{h,l})\to f(0)$.

Comment: You want to say $h<\xi_{h,l}<h+l$ rather than $0<\xi_{h,l}<h+l$.

Comment: @Medo $0<\xi_{h,l}<h+l$ is true and sufficient anyways.

Comment: It is true and sufficient, but when you state the stronger statement $h<\xi_{h,l}<h+l$ you also give the hint that the argument is true for any small $h$ positive or negative...